# How can I reprogram Recent (menu) hardware key on all of the Android apps from my app?

Tags: android, menu, key, overriding, hardware

I`m trying to add some features to my Android app, like reprogram Recent (menu) key on a device, so it can perform some action defined by me, like, do nothing or restrict that button on android device. So far, i have seen some answers, but i didn't get the right solution.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Example case:
My app is opened and the user chooses to disable that key. My app is closed and the key is disabled until the user goes again in my app and turn it on.

[image]

Comment: That should not be possible, except through a custom ROM or perhaps a rooted device.

Comment: @CommonsWare
But I find an app on Google Play Store that does the job: All in one gestures
[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phoenixstudios.aiogestures&hl=en) and my phone (Samsung S7) is not rooted.